# The block is not displaying after loading the page

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, factory, dynamic-blocks

Please help solve this puzzle.
I'm created `after` plugin, after load category widget. The collection of items must be used in the js. The idea is to simply intercept the collection in the plugin, load it to the front in the .phtml template and process it in it. My plugin code
**ParceWidget.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class ParceWidget
{
    protected $blockFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory
    ) {
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    }

    public function afterCreateCollection(
        \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList $subject,
        $itemsCollection
    ) {
        $this->parceWidgetInformation($itemsCollection);

        return $itemsCollection;
    }
    
    protected function parceWidgetInformation($itemsCollection)
    {
        $block = $this->blockFactory->createBlock(
            Template::class,
            [
                'data' => [
                    'widget_items' => $itemsCollection
                ]
            ]
        )
            ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::widget.phtml');

        $block->setNameInLayout('vendor.module.widget');
        $block->toHtml();
    }
}
```

**widget.phtml**

```
<div>
    <?php if ($items = $this->getData('widget_items')):?>
        <?php //var_dump($items); die();?>
        <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
            <ul>
                <li><?= $item->getData()?></li>
            </ul>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

I have omitted some of the standard points, leaving the gist.
So, if you write any content in `widget.phtml`, then at the end of loading the page on the front will not be displayed. But if you stop the download page process by doing for example:
`<?php var_dump($items')); die();?>`
In this case, everything will be in place. Here I have a question, where does the data disappear in the process of loading the page, because you can see that the template is loaded and the data can be obtained in it?

Comment: please paste widget.phtml

Comment: @BilalUsean - thanks for viewed, updated post